# Increasing duration of message notification popup in Slack

Tags: debian, slack

I'm using Slack desktop (on Debian Bullseye) and I found one feature very useful - message popups on receiving a message.

However, they only show for under a second and then disappear, which is annoying and doesn't let me fully read it, which I find convenient.

I haven't found anything in Preferences to change that. Is there any way to lengthen that time?

Comment: Also, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72607407/is-there-a-way-to-increase-slack-notification-popup-timeout

Comment: I wrote I'm using Slack desktop.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid Re duplicate: that question has no answer, accepted and working at least.

Answer (score 0):

I found an awful half-solution for KDE: you can increase overall notification popup duration.

[image]

This is global notification duration though, so it's not limited just to Slack.

Notification in KDE are handled by `knotify` which does have an option for how long popup is displayed. So in principle popups could definitely be handled by Slack this way.

I really don't need KDE notification duration be set for *all* popups. Don't particularly care for "file has been moved to trash" hang there for say 10 seconds.